# ¿Cómo puedo prohibir que un mismo archivo se suba 2 veces?

Tags: php, html, jquery, form-submit

Al darle al submit, antes si le daba 4 o 5 veces, se subían 4 o 5 archivos, ahora he creado una verificación y si le das varias veces, siempre de máximo se suben 2, ¿cómo puedo hacer que rechaze el servidor el segundo?

El form:

```
<form name="myForm" method="post" action="upload.php"  onsubmit="return validateForm()" autocomplete="off">
<div id="txtar1"><textarea id="input" rows="34" cols="165" type="text" name="input" pattern=".{10,}" autofocus></textarea></div>
<br />
<br />
<div id="save1"><input type="submit" id="smitbtn" class="save-b" value="Save" /></div>
</form>
```

El **validateForm()**

```
<script> 
function validateForm() {
var x = document.forms["myForm"]["input"].value;
if (x == "") {
    document.getElementById( "input" ).focus();
    return false;
}else {
    $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
}
}
</script>
```

Con este codigo he dado click mucha veces, y siempre de límite se sube 2 veces el mismo archivo

¿Ayuda?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la función de PHP "file_exists". Solo debes indicarle la ruta y la función te devuelve true, si existe, o false sino existe. Acá puedes encontrar la documentación. http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php    . Te dejo un ejemplo simple

```
<?php
$archivo = '/path/to/foo.txt';

if (file_exists($archivo)) {
    echo "El archivo $archivo existe";
} else {
    echo "El archivo $archivo no existe";
}
?>
```

Comment: Mi upload.php, crea un archivo con un nombre aleatorio, ¿cómo podría hacerlo? Si le doy varias veces, se suben varios archivos con diferentes nombres

Answer (score 1):

Puedes controlarlo del lado del Front sin necesidad de molestar la Back. Si no, @Raul te dió ya la respuesta, esta puede ser una alterna, pero muy prometedora.

```js
$(function(){
  var flag = 1;
  $(document).on('click','#myButton',function(e){
   if(flag === 2){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Ya no puedes enviar el formulario');
   } 
   
   else{
    flag++;
    alert('Se envió el formulario');
    //$('#myForm').submit(); //Descomentar para enviar el formulario
   }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="POST" action="foo.php" id="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="bar">
  <input type="button" id="myButton" value="Enviar">
</form>
```